# Оптимальный способ хранения небольшой таблицы данных для java приложения

Tags: java, sql, база-данных

Интересует спрособ хранения данных небольшой таблицы, 2000 строк и 6 столбцов. Данные статичны, обновление требуется не чаще чем раз в неделю, int и String значения минимальной длины. Интересует именно скорость обмена данными с данной таблицей. Стоит ли подключать для этого SQL или просто выгружать данные из xml файла в java класс?
В программировании новичек, не судите строго.

Comment: а как планируете использовать данные? как обращаться? сразу весь объем или поиск по условию?

Comment: Данные планируются использовать для быстрого поиска единичных значений, либо выборки нескольких значений в условиях поиска. В данной реализации обращение к java классу через servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На таком незначительном объеме понятие "скорость" малоприменимо.

Хранение в текстовом файле (я бы порекомендовал CSV, а не XML) с полной загрузкой в оперативку будет незначительно быстрее. Также удобно обновлять данные просто заменой файла. Минусы - писать свой велосипед.

Хранение во встраиваемой БД (например, SQLite) - удобство выборки. Обновлять также можно заменой файла БД, но только при закрытом приложении.

Выделенный SQL-сервер в данном случае даст только минусы.

Comment: Думал реализовать с помощью сериализации в xml. благо что готовые решения уже имею. Насчет встраиваемой БД спасибо за совет. Не работал но думаю стоит изучить. В целом благодарю за интерес, проявленный к моей проблеме.